# Estimote beacon security

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, estimote

I have Estimote Developer Preview Kit. By the Estimote Android app I can change major and minor ids of the beacons. So anybody can change major and minor ids of beacons. How can I secure the beacons?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by security? you want to have the beacons change in a way so that they cannot be spoofed or perhaps you mean protection from unauthorized change of major and minor.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't currently possible unless you use the Secure UUID feature in the latest version of the iOS SDK.

Also check this conversation over at the estimote website:

https://community.estimote.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203574206-Security-concerns-on-Android-